# How to select each row and highlight / unselect each row and highlight from data api call

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my table on start

```
<div class= "col-md-7" id = "recyclable-list" >
            
                                <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th style=" padding-left:25px;";>RecyclableID</th>
                                    <th style=" padding-left:100px;">Name</th>
                                    <th style=" text-align: center;">RecyclableType</th>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="recycleTable">

                                </tbody>
                                
                              </table>
```

This is my script call for database

```
var myarray = [];


                            $.ajax({
                            
                                url:"https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8080/api/get",
                        
                                method:"GET",
                                // In this case, we are going to use headers as
                                headers:{
                                    // The query you're planning to call
                                    // i.e. <query> can be UserGet(0), RecyclableGet(0), etc.
                                    query:"RecyclableGet(0)",
                                    
                                    // Gets the apikey from the sessionStorage
                                    apikey:sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
                                },
                    
                                success:function(data,xhr,textStatus) {
                                
                                myarray = data;
                                buildTable(myarray);
                                console.log(myarray);
                                

                                },

                                error:function(xhr,textStatus,err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                }
                            });

                            function buildTable(data){
                                var table = document.getElementById("recycleTable")

                                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                                    var row = `<tr>
                                                <td>${data[i].RecyclableID}</td>
                                                <td>${data[i].Name}</td>
                                                <td>${data[i].RecyclableType}</td>
                                        </tr>`

                                        table.innerHTML += row
                                        
                                }
                            };
```

This is my hightlight Js file

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#recyclable-list").on('click',function() {
      var selected =  $('#recycleTable tr').on('click',async function(){
         await $('#recycleTable tr').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
         
        });

        $("#edit").prop('disabled',false);
        $("#edit").removeClass('btn btn-secondary');
        $("#edit").addClass('btn btn-primary');
        $("#delete").prop('disabled',false);

      if (!selected)
      $(this).find('#recycleTable tr').addClass("highlight") & $('#recycleTable tr').removeClass('highlight');
    
        else 
        $("#edit").prop('disabled',true) & $("#delete").prop('disabled',true) & $("#edit").removeClass('btn btn-primary') & $("#edit").addClass('btn btn-secondary');;
        
        
    });
  });
```

and this is my css style for highlight

```
    .recycleTable.highlight{
         background-color: #ddd;
        }
```

But however the highlight now is selecting the whole table row instead of row by row, does anyone have any idea how to i change it to select row per row instead of the the whole row ?

[image: row selected the whole table instead]

Now the selected whole table have been fix but however i am unable to unselect the row i choose and button is not enabled when selected a row

[image: row selected but cant un select]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

Dynamically added `<tr>` must have the `"click"` event delegated to a parent element that's been there since the DOM was loaded (ie hard coded in HTML). In this case the `<tbody>` is a good canident. One extra parameter is needed:

> ```
> /*
> 'tr' delegates click events to any <tr> within
> the <tbody> whether static or dynamic.
> */
> $('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {...
> ```

First of all, never use `#id`, use `class`, otherwise you have hindered your code -- that's especially true if you are using jQuery. `#id` is useful in circumstances such as Bootstrap plugins, but not much else. The example below uses only classes.

This will allow only a single `<tr>` to be highlighted and also removes highlighting if the `<tr>` was already highlighted.

> ```
> $('tbody tr').not($(this)).removeClass('highlight');
> $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
> ```

This will disable the `<button>`s if there's a highlighted `<tr>`

> ```
> const btns = $('.btn-group button');
> ...
> if ($(this).hasClass('highlight')) {
>   btns.prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled dark');
> } else {
>   btns.prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled dark');
> }
> ```

## ```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .highlight {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    button {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
    }
    
    .dark {
      background-color: #000;
      color: #666;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="fluid-container">
    <fieldset class='btn-group'>
      <button class='add btn btn-success'>Add Row</button>
      <button class='dark edit btn btn-primary disabled change-row' disabled>Edit</button>
      <button class='type btn btn-warning'>Add Type</button>
      <button class='dark delete btn btn-danger disabled change-row' disabled>Delete</button>
    </fieldset>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>User Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </main>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    const buildTable = data => {
      const table = document.querySelector('.table tbody');

      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let row = `<tr>
    <td>${data[i].name}</td>
    <td>${data[i].username}</td>
    <td>${data[i].email}</td>
    </tr>`;
        table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', row);
      }
    };

    const getData = async(url) => {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const json = await response.json();
      return buildTable(json);
    };
  getData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/');

    $(document).ready(function() {
      const btns = $('.change-row');
      $("tbody").on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
        /* //Add this line if you want only a single row selected
    
        $('tbody tr').not($(this)).removeClass('highlight');
        */
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');

        if ($('tbody tr').hasClass('highlight')) {
          btns.prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled dark');
        } else {
          btns.prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled dark');
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hi but i am calling my api from database to the td 
not writing any tr into the tbody 
is there my code i can select the row and unselect the row

Comment: @Flow can you rephrase that? What you're saying is confusing.

Comment: oh i mean that i am calling the api directly to the tbody where now my problem is that after $('#recycleTable tr').on('click',async function(){await $('#recycleTable tr').removeClass('highlight'); $(this).addClass('highlight');}); 
i can highlight the row and move the highlight to the next row but i  am unable to deselect it

Comment: So you want multiple rows highlighted and unselect as well?

Comment: nope as in just unselect for now using the code i have given and try and test

Comment: The code you have is bad (hence your problem).  Describe what behavior you want.

Comment: Do you want only a single row highlighted or multiple rows highlighted. If you tested my code you'll see that any row can be deselected already. The buttons act as requested as well.

Comment: i have paste the code to it for the javascript however it dont work
and my button cant be inside table tr as is it design my team to put beside on the search bar category while i change the button class and edited nothing happen the row is not select at all but i will test create a plain html and import the api to see if works

Comment: I can't guarantee 100% compliance with cut and paste, I changed the HTML because `#id`s are bad practice and there is no HTML for the buttons.  After the table is built review the HTML with F12. There may be unexpected changes.

Comment: ah i just copy the whole code and paste into my visual studio code in a new html page and call the api from tbody as expected the row cant be select or click anymore 
here the image https://imgur.com/a/GcYFdij

Comment: @Flow Ok see update.

Comment: not sure if u see my chat i have some trouble with the authorization do u have anyway for me to store the api session key from json as i am using ajax to store originally when from login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239855/discussion-between-zer00ne-and-flow).

Answer (score 1):

Click event on tbody? not a good idea, i suggest you to change your code to this :

```
...
$("#recyclable-list").on('click',function() {
  var selected = $(this).find('#recycleTable').hasClass("highlight");
  ...
  if (!selected)
    $(this).find('#recycleTable').addClass("highlight");
...
```

Comment: hi after i change this my row cant be selected anymore do u know why ?

Comment: yeah because the event is called on the Table ( it is above the tr and tr events wont work) , you can add a separated refresh button and assign the event to that button

Comment: is it possible not to call a button but just auto load the table to it ?

Comment: There should be an event to call the data load function , when do you want to load items again (refresh) ?

Comment: hi is working now the highlight but is selecting the whole row again
https://imgur.com/a/NDdSyR0

The whole table when click is selected is it possible to make it select per row from my data load ?

Comment: are you talking about the background color?
or you want to refresh data when selecting any row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239826/discussion-between-flow-and-john).

Comment: hi i added my question for more details now i want to select highlight and unselect and unhighlight  while when high light the button are enabled and when unhighlight the button are back to disabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239852/discussion-between-flow-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

You care calling id but your declaration is a class.  Change from `.` to `#` as in `#recycleTable.highlight`

Comment: Thanks but now i found out that my js file could be the problem as is highlight the whole table now instead row per row